# Passing a List of Radio buttons objects to my Action Method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a security metrix page similar to the below:-
[image]

currently i have the following code inside my view:-

```
@foreach(var item in Model.PermisionLevel.OrderByDescending(a=>a.PermisionSize)){
<th>
</th>}
</tr>
 @{
int i =0 ;
foreach (var item2 in Model.TechnologyType.OrderBy(a=>a.Name)) { 
<tr>
<td class="f">
@item2.Name
</td>
@foreach (var item3 in Model.PermisionLevel.OrderByDescending(a=>a.PermisionSize))
       {
<td class="f">

                @Html.RadioButton(item2.Name, item3.PermisionLevelID)
                @Html.Hidden("AssetTypeID" , item2.AssetTypeID)
                @Html.Hidden("PermisionLevelID",item3.PermisionLevelID)
                @Html.Hidden("SecurityRoleID",Model.SecurityRole.SecurityRoleID)
             </td>
} 
</tr>
}
}
```

and the following ActionMethod:-

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AssignPermisionLevel(ICollection<SecurityroleTypePermision> list)
        {
            foreach (var c in list)
            {
                repository.InsertOrUpdateSecurityroleTypePermisions(c);
            }
            repository.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

But i am not sure about how i can pass the associated hidden field values only if the related radio button was checked. currently if i submit the view , the action method will raise a null exception?
Can anyone advice on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

each radio group has a name, which looks like your item2.Name.

```
// see if this group is selected
var radWebSite = $('[name="SomeName"]:checked');
if (radWebSite.length > 0) {
    // this group has a selection, get the value
    var WebSiteVal = radWebSite.val();
}
```

if you get all of your answers into variables or some object, you can pass that down to your action method, here is a suggestion

```
$('#SaveClick').click(function() {
    var SavePermissions = {};
    SavePermissions.WebSite = WebSiteVal // this is the variable from above
    // .... do this for each radio group

    var DTO = { 'DTO': SavePermissions };

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            url: "/ControllerName/ActionMethodName",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
            success: function (data) {
                // do success stuff
            },
            error: function(data){
                // do error stuff
            },
            complete: function () {
                //do final stuff
            }
        });
});
```

Then in your action method create a class that has a property for each item you put in SavePermissions on the javascript, probably should even call it SavePermissions

```
public ActionResult AssignPermisionLevel(SavePermissions DTO){
    // save stuff
}
```

**Edit: **
I didn't think about this before, but we have a reference to Newtonsoft.Json in our application, you'll probably need that to do this...

Comment: but will your approach be able to retrive the values for the hidden fields for the selected radio button ?